# Parsing time from google sheets to html and date information is being added

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm parsing data from a google sheet to a html table.  One of the cells only has time information but I'm still getting date information.  Here is a code snipit:

```
Logger.log("Date:  "+ data[0][q]+":  "+data[k][q]);
var tempTime =Utilities.formatDate(data[k][q], "GMT", "hh:mm");
Logger.log("short time:  "+tempTime);
temp2 = str2snd;
temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td>Test:  "+tempTime+" Real:  "+data[k]q]+"</td></tr>";
str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
```

That little bit of code yields:

> Test: 07:30 Real: Thu Aug 07 2014 15:30:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

What I need that field to show is 15:30 without all of the date information.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  The full function is below.

Thanks so much!

Loren

```
function updDate(date){
  //Logger.log("Update called with date:  "+date);
  var searchString = date;
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("blahblahblah");
  var data = s2.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();

 var row = new Array();



  //Logger.log("Setup complete");

  var k;


  for (var i in data) {
    //Logger.log("length is:  "+data[i].length)
    //var p = data[i].length
    for (var j in data[i]) {
      //Logger.log("We are at i:  "+i) //Row
      //Logger.log("We are at j:  "+j) //Col
      if (i !=0){
        if(data[i][j] != ""){
          if(j == 4){
            //Logger.log("date from picker:  " + date);
            //Logger.log("date from Data:  " + data[i][j]);
            var ssDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][j], "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
            //Logger.log("date post Convert:  " +ssDate);
            if(date == ssDate){


              k= i
              var p = data[i].length
              //Logger.log("P is:  " +p);

            }
          }

        }
        }
      }
    }
  //Logger.log("K is:  "+k)
  var str2snd;
  str2snd = "<table style="+'"'+"width:500px"+'"'+">"
  var q = 1
  while (q <= p){
    var temp1;
    var temp2; 

    if(data[k][q] !=""){


      if(q==4){
        Logger.log("q==4");
        Logger.log("Header is:  "+data[0][q]);
          temp2 = str2snd;
          var ssDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[k][q], "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
          temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td>"+ssDate+"</td></tr>";
          str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
      }else{
        if(q == 6){
          temp2 = str2snd;
          temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td><a href="+'"'+data[k][q]+'"'+">Gig Coord Link</a></td></tr>";
          str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
        }else{
          if(q==8){
            temp2 = str2snd;
            temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td><a href="+'"'+data[k][q]+'"'+">Pgm Notes Link</a></td></tr>";
            str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
            }else{
              if(q==29){
                temp2 = str2snd;
                temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td><a href="+'"'+data[k][q]+'"'+">Input List Link</a></td></tr>";
                str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
              }else{
                if(q==10){
                  Logger.log("Date:  "+ data[0][q]+":  "+data[k][q]);
                  var tempTime =Utilities.formatDate(data[k][q], "GMT", "hh:mm");
                  Logger.log("short time:  "+tempTime);
                  temp2 = str2snd;
                  temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td>Test:  "+tempTime+" Real:  "+data[k][q]+"</td></tr>";
                  str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
                  }else{
                  if(q==33){
                    temp2 = str2snd;
                    temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td><a href="+'"'+data[k][q]+'"'+">Mediafire Link</a></td></tr>";
                    str2snd = temp2 + temp1;

                }else{
                  temp2 = str2snd;
                  temp1 = "<tr><td>"+data[0][q]+"</td><td>"+data[k][q]+"</td></tr>";
                  str2snd = temp2 + temp1;
                }
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    //<a href="url">Link text</a>
    q++

  }
   str2snd = str2snd + "</table>"; 
  //Logger.log("finished with:  " + str2snd);
  return str2snd;
  }
```

Comment: Since you know how to use utilities.formatDate why don't you simply use it to send values to HTML as plain strings instead of date objects?

Comment: @Sergeinsas Why is the format that I used so far off of the actual time?

Comment: date objects in javaScript are always complete dates with year, month, day,hours... even if the spreadsheet has only time value in a cell. When the script reads a time value in SS it converts it to a full date object. Was that your question ? I'm not sure I understand fully your code because I have no idea how is your data in the spreadsheet...(actually that's why I used comment and not answer ;-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas The time listed nested in the date is correct (1530) the time that I attempted to correct with the formatDate is off by 8 hours.  Is there some sort of offset that I need to implement?

Comment: that's because you use "GMT" replace it by Session.getScriptTimeZone() and it will be ok for your TZ

Comment: I meant  you use GMT string in utilities.FormatDate() argument... wasn't very clear, sorry !

Comment: I wrote it as an answer, please consider accepting it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date objects in javaScript are always complete dates with year, month, day,hours... even if the spreadsheet has only time value in a cell.

When the script reads a time value in SS it converts it to a full date object, to show the date values (date or time, the origin object is exactly the same) use

`Utilities.formatDate(data[k][q], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mm");`

to send a string to your HTML Ui instead of a date object.

```
`Session.getScriptTimeZone()`
```

gets the time zone from your script so that hours  (and dates in certain conditions) show the right values.

For this to work correctly you have to check the time zone settings of your spreadsheet as well, and the one of your script. Both should be set to your country of course.