# How to display timestamp from spreadsheet to html table

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

On my previous post, I needed my table to refreshed. Now, I've created a website using app script and I have this login form that once you input some info it will stored in my spreadsheet with a timestamp on it. However, the timestamp is not showing on the table. Is there a way to fix this?

[image] However, nothing displays on the table when the values are stored in the SS. I still need to change the formatting style for Column A into "Plain text" so that all values from Column A-D will be displayed to this table:

[image: HTML TABLE]

I've looked into this answered but I don't know how to do it.
[Parsing time from google sheets to html and date information is being added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432082/parsing-time-from-google-sheets-to-html-and-date-information-is-being-added).

Can someone help me? It's very frustrating, been working on this for the whole week.

Here's my code:

```js
<script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
  
  setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById("tablebody").innerHTML = "";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getOnline();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getOnline).generateTable();
  }, 5000); // run the function every 5 seconds
  

});

   

 function generateTable(dataArray){

  var tbody = document.getElementById("tablebody");
  var tbody1 = document.getElementById("tablebody").innerHTML;
  
  dataArray.forEach(function(r){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.textContent = r[0];
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.textContent = r[1];
  var col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.textContent = r[2];
  var col4 = document.createElement("td");
  col4.textContent = r[3]; // modified code
  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);
  row.appendChild(col4);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
});
 
}

</script>
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5;}

    input[type=text], select {
      width: 95%;
      padding: 10px 10px;
      margin: 5px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

```html
<h1> Current Users</h1>
  <p> The table will automatically refresh every 5 seconds to display new users </p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>SHIFT</th>
      </tr>
     <tbody id="tablebody">
    </table>
```

and here's my code on .gs

```
function getOnline(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("UserLogins");
    var data = ws.getRange(3, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1,4).getValues();
    Logger.log(data);
    return data;    
}
```

Thank you in advance! Happy new year :)

Comment: Can you post sample data and the current results you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass the `3rd` element to `col4`, but instead you pass the `2nd` twice.

Replace the `dataArray.forEach` code with this:

```
dataArray.forEach(function(r){
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var col1 = document.createElement("td");
  col1.textContent = r[0];
  var col2 = document.createElement("td");
  col2.textContent = r[1];
  var col3 = document.createElement("td");
  col3.textContent = r[2];
  var col4 = document.createElement("td");
  col4.textContent = r[3]; // modified code
  row.appendChild(col1);
  row.appendChild(col2);
  row.appendChild(col3);
  row.appendChild(col4);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
});
```

Comment: I've upadated my code above. The timestamp is still not showing on the table :(

Comment: In order for the data to get displayed in the table, I need to change the formatting of the date into "Plain text". Is there a much easier way that when the text is stored in the SS it will automatically displayed in the table?